# ASP.NET text box loses text on partial postback

Tags: c#, user-controls, webforms, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a user control,

In user control I have a button, which when is clicked, shows a message box ,

message box has a textbox and another button,

when I click on another button, I need to get textbox value in code behind, but it's not happening at all, as button is doing partial postback and textbox just loses it's state.

**I can't get textbox value in page_load method and save it to session state as textbox is populating dynamically**

this is what i tried so far,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
```

and

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string button1text = TextBox1Text;
```

and

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get 
        {
            return Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] as string;  
        }
        set
        {
            Page.Session["TextBox1Text"] = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

> No Gain but Only Pain.

Comment: Did you try to add the dynamically added control to page using like this `Page.Controls.Add`.

Comment: i am adding user control to my webpart, which is a control in page, it's sharepoint, sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I used UpdatePanels, but I believe that on partial postback they only send updated values for controls inside them. So move the TextBox inside the UpdatePanel, or perhaps use Javascript to populate a hidden control inside the UpdatePanel with the contexts of the TextBox whenever it is updated.

Comment: +1, i was thinking about that but I don't think this is the best way of doing it, sir

Answer (score 1):

in ASP page

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hidtext" runat="server" value="">
```

in C#

```
    hidtext.Value=textbox1.text;
```

or VB

```
     hidtext.Value=textbox1.text
```

after post back

```
    textbox1.text=hidtext.value;
```